# Reading data through S3 bucket using lambda function

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to read data from a s3 bucket through a lambda and the file is an excel file (.xlsx)
but when i print the stream it is empty.

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var ss = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {

 var file = ss.getObject({ Bucket: 'kapoorbck', Key: 'testdata.xlsx' }).createReadStream();
//console.log(file);
   var buffers = [];

  file.on('data', (data) => {
    buffers.push(data);
  });
console.log(buffers);


file.on('end', function () {
    var buffer = Buffer.concat(buffers);
    var workbook = xlsx.read(buffer);
    //var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;

    console.log(workbook);
});



return{
  statusCode :200,
  body : "Success"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don 't see anything wrong wrong with core logic, apart from two things

1. You are trying to print the `console.log(buffers);` synchronously. Reading it from stream is an async operation so the console.log needs to be inside either `data` event listener or `end` event listener.
2. Second thing is your return statement, that is also at the end so it will be executed first as it will not wait for the asychronous operation to finish. You need to move it inside the end event listener so lambda knows when to return and finish the job.

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you provide me the code . I am new to async programming and bieng worked on structural programming the concept is difficult to me

Comment: Sure. Give me some time. Will put the code. In the mean time try putting your return in end event listener and move your console in data event listener.